# Tough time importing .dxf into blender

Tags: import

here's the file:
https://mega.nz/#!OFo1QBgR!iECp6YBlRXYUVcdfEmoLO-w7g76yP6qfaRy8hbP9IZ8

I've fiddled with the settings, but everytime, it just imports as a bunch of plane axies, i've confirmed that they do open and work in autocad, but blender is much easier to work with....

please help

Comment: Check that answer for some suggestion. What you are more interested in is to center the dxf in the origin: http://i.imgur.com/v9Na7TA.jpg

Comment: if possible, can you just give me that file?   i imported it by the instructions, but still no mesh after lots of scaling (i see verticies count though)

Comment: Fastes way always to put the geometry already in the origin in CAD before exporting in DXF. Here's the file:http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/477/